# Creating arrow with rounded corners

Tags: html, css

I have this design, in which there is a slanted arrow before each box:

[image]

I made the arrows using the CSS pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after`.
Here is  [the code I wrote](http://jsfiddle.net/KgpVX/)

and they came out like this:

[image]

As you can see, the arrows in the design are a little more rounded than the ones actually created. I don't really know how to change this.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Fairly certain this can't be done. You can apply `border-radius` to the bottom of the arrow, but that's the opposite of what you want. Why not use an image?

Comment: @JezenThomas, I was wondering if it can be done without an image. I'd rather use css that images

Comment: Why? You don't get bonus points for making a simple task more complicated. Even if this could be hacked together, how maintainable would it be across browsers?

Comment: @JezenThomas, I'm not looking for a hack. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking a solution....

Comment: you could use a svg path instead..

Comment: Your best option would be to use svg elements with some text element inside.

Answer (score 2):

Rounding isn't supported in css borders but it is supported in svg's stroke using:

`stroke-linecap: round;` and `stroke-linejoin: round;`

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="-1 -1 100 100">
  <polyline points="10,10 10,0 0,10" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" stroke="red"/> 
</svg>
```

It is limited in flexibility but does offer some manipulation and can produce, albeit small, rounded edges.

```css
.slider-pagination {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #dedede;
}

.sld-menu-item {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 0 13px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 106px;
  height: 85px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  /*nicer box-shadow for webkit and mozilla. later - less nice bordershadow for IE8*/
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  /*rachel's shadow*/
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  behavior: url(/singa/wp-content/themes/singalovsky/PIE.htc);
  list-style: none;
}

.sld-menu-item span {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85%;
  height: 61px;
  color: #414141;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 8px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  kit-transition: background 1s linear;
  -moz-transition-property: color, background;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease, ease;
  -o-transition: background 1s ease-out;
  transition: background 1s linear;
}

.sld-menu-item svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.sld-menu-item polyline {
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 18;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  fill: #e5e5e5;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
}
```

```html
<ul class="slider-pagination clearfix" id="slider-pagination">
  <li onclick="slideshow.pos(0)" class="sld-menu-item sld-menu-item-1 selected">
    <span title="תחומי לימוד"></span>
    <svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="10 -20 100 100">  
      <polyline points="100,100 100,0 0,100"/>
    </svg>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this http://cssarrowplease.com - simple and almost supports all browsers  ,

Your design having border **outside** (stroke- outside/inside/center) which is possible to do only with Photoshop and not with css,

Hence you cant do with it with css :)

So I think You should use Image/svg